# Deploying on Heroku - Images disappears after upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, heroku, deployment, paperclip

I deployed an application on Heroku which I wrote on Ruby on Rails. It is a movie review app.

I am able to upload images from my computer, to the web app online. Everything else works as per my expectations.

The images disappear after a day. My requirement is to have the image continue to render.

I am using Paperclip gem from rails. This only happens on the deployed version and not on localhost.

[image]

Comment: There is not enough information to help you here. Show us some source code.

Comment: On a side note, it should be "This was crap", not "cramp"

Comment: thanks I will bear that in mind next time!. lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default upload location on Heroku is into temporary storage. This is because you will get a different web worker each time you deploy.

You need to use S3 or another location to store your files. Luckily this is well documented for [Paperclip on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3).

The main configuration difference is this. Add `gem 'aws-sdk'` to your Gemfile and then adjust your config file in  `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```

Comment: where abouts in the config folder do Include the paperclip_defaults? e.g, application, database, environments...?

Comment: Apologies. This is within config/environments/production.rb